# Can't initialise Contract for view after adding payable fallback or receive function

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have 2 contracts

```
contract BetContract {
    address owner;
    string title;
    
    
    function GetTitle(string memory title) public view returns(string){
        return this.title;
    }
}

contract Main {
    .
    .
    
    function GetBetTitle(address betAddress) public view returns(string){
        BetContract currentBet = BetContract(betAddress);
        return currentBet.GetTitle();
    }
}
```

That works great, but as soon as I want add a fallback or receive function to BetContract, I can't initialise the BetContract anymore without making it payable?!

```
contract BetContract {
    address owner;
    string title;
    
    
    receive()external payable{
        
    }
    
    function GetTitle(string memory title) public view returns(string){
        return this.title;
    }
}

contract Main {
   .
   .

   function GetBetTitle(address betAddress) public view returns(string){
       BetContract currentBet = BetContract(betAddress);

TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from non-payable "address" to "contract BetContract", which has a payable fallback function.

       return currentBet.GetTitle();
   }}
```

Any solutions for that? Thank you all

I tried to call the function on other ways, but I need to know why this is the case

Comment: What Solidity version you're using? Based on the syntax, I'm assuming (deprecated) v0.4.x... Please edit the question so it contains minimal reproducible example - so that answerers are able to copy-paste your code and get the same error as you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address needs to be made `payable` first:

```
function GetBetTitle(address betAddress) public view returns(string){
       BetContract currentBet = BetContract(payable(betAddress));

       return currentBet.GetTitle();
   }
```